# Ruby 2/Rails 4 - How to get Julian Date of "created_at"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, julian-date

I am trying to generate an incident_number in my Incident model as follows:

```
  def incident_number
    (self.created_at.strftime("%Y") + self.created_at.jd.to_s + self.id.to_s).to_i
  end
```

I am receiving an error that "jd" is an undefined method.

I can call Date.Today.jd to get the Julian Date of today, but how do I get the Julian Date of the "created_at" date?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the `created_at` to `Date` type of an object:

```
self.created_at.to_date.jd.to_s
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you! I will accept your answer when it allows me to!